# Typing React Router Router Component? Confused

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-redux

I have not used React Router v4, so I could be making some novice errors. My issue is that Typescript compilation is breaking on an error that I've seen where I guess there is potentially a class that is being returned under the hood that I am not seeing?

Code ::

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Router, RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';
import HomeRoute from './home';
import PhotosRoute from './photos';
import StoreRoute from './store';
import TourRoute from './tour';
import 'index.css';

interface RouterProps {
  component?: React.SFC<RouteComponentProps<any> | void> | React.ComponentClass<RouteComponentProps<any> | void>;
}

class Navigation extends React.Component<RouterProps, {}> {
  render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
       <Router>
        <div>
          <ul className="nav-styles">
           <li>
               <HomeRoute />
            </li>
            <li>
               <PhotosRoute />
            </li>
            <li>
               <StoreRoute />
            </li>
            <li>
                <TourRoute />
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default Navigation;
```

error ::

```
(16,8): error TS2322: Type '{ children: Element; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Router> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Re...'.
  Type '{ children: Element; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<RouterProps>'.
    Property 'history' is missing in type '{ children: Element; }'.
```

In case I am doing something wrong or someone wishes to see it, here is an example of `HomeRoute`. However I don't see this being the breaking issue at this time.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from '../Home/Home';

export default (): JSX.Element => (
  <div>
    <nav>
      <Link to="/">Home</Link>
    </nav>
    <div>
      <Route path="/" component={ Home } />
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

I know I need to type the class somehow, and I have been trying and can't figure out a good reference or how to type the Navigation class.

Answer (score 11):

I think you forgot to add the history to your `<Router />` element.

Can you try:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

[...]

const history = createBrowserHistory();

[...]

class Navigation extends React.Component<RouterProps, {}> {
  render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
       <Router history={history}>
        <div>
          <ul className="nav-styles">
          [...]
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: For what it's worth I fixed it, but I have been ignoring the history error by tslint:disable so thank you for the types I will install these.

Comment: @cheussy How did you fix it?

Comment: Or you can just import it like so: `import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';` which will handle the history for you.

Answer (score 11):

I made the same 'novice' error when following along the react-router tutorial:

```
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';
```

...should instead be:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Answer (score 5):

`Router` is the base interface for higher level routers [[1]](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router). It requires history to be injected as a prop to compile. Depending on your production environment, I recommend either `BrowserRouter` or `NativeRouter` instead.

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router[1](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router)